# split combo box click and toggle button click in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, mahapps.metro

Currently,I am using `MahApps.Metro` Combo Box and Can i split event of Combo box click event and toggle button click? Like this=>

[Please Check Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tVAV.png)

My requirement is when i click `Click 1`,I don't want to show drop down list and just do click event.
But when i click `Click 2`,I just want to show drop down list and not trigger click event.

How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: one idea can be to check the source of click event (preview mouse down or some other event) and handle the event if it's not from toggle button.

Comment: @swamy, Thanks for the idea but How can I determine that event is coming from where?

Comment: You can check the source/original source of the event args in case of mouse events. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @swamy, Thanks, Its work now.